# Why does the predicate naming convention differ between different functions?

Tags: lisp, naming-conventions, common-lisp

I am a Common Lisp newbie who's beginning to learn the language. My question is: I've seen several functions use the predicate syntax in different ways. For example (just looked this up), there is streamp and pathnamep, but there is also input-stream-p and output-stream-p. Why aren't all functions standardized to use *p or *-p? Is this maybe just a historical artifact?

Comment: Mostly historical -- Common Lisp largely ended up as a simple union of everything from every major Lisp implementation at the time, almost all thrown in together with more interest in ensuring that existing code would continue to work than in creating a language that really fit together well.

Comment: This isn't actually 'syntax' - it is 'naming convention'

Comment: @GoZoner Good point, fixed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rule is that **one-word predicate names end in just `P`**, while **multi-word predicate names end in `-P`**.  The reason for the former is mostly historical; the reason for the latter is that a name like `input-streamp` would wrongly suggest that the question being asked is “is this input a stream?” or something like that.

Comment: I tend to say `predicatep` and `complex-predicate-p` (or, alternatively `simplep` and `complex-predicate-p`) as a rule.

Comment: Note also that in some cases, you do not add an hyphen for multi-word predicate (e.g. `string-lessp`). See [Common Lisp the Language, 2nd Edition](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node69.html).

Comment: And also there is `atom` :) .[Common Lisp the Language, 2nd Edition](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node73.html)